# why instanceof operator safer than constructor property in determining object type?

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, instanceof

I was reading on "professional javascript for web developers" when the author said :

> The constructor property was originally intended for use in identifying the object type. However, the
> instanceof operator is considered to be a safer way of determining type
> [image]

can you explain what is the concern behind not using `constructor` over `instanceof` to determine object type?

traditional example with no differences maybe like:

```
car instanceof Car  // true
car.constructor === Car // true
```

Thanks...

Comment: might have to do with subclasses. if B is a subclass of A, `constructor` will return false but `instanceof` will return true

Comment: `car.constructor = "I'm not a constructor"`

Comment: @VLAZ if you do that, will it still run the constructor defined in the class when you call `new Class`?

Comment: answer is yes, it will

Comment: @TKoL yes. Because we add a new property to the instance itself, however, the constructor that comes from the prototype would stay but would be "shadowed". You can get it by doing `Object.getPrototypeOf(car).constructor`. However, OP is asking for `car.constructor === Car` and *that* would fail. EDIT: you can also overwrite that constructor, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
class A {

}

class B extends A {

}

var x = new B();

console.log('instanceof A', x instanceof A);
console.log('instanceof B', x instanceof B);
console.log('constructor = A', x.constructor === A);
console.log('constructor = B', x.constructor === B);
```

Subclassing makes a difference

Comment: thanks , The author wasn't know about es6 at that time of publishing the book . could you adding es5 version to make it easier for me

Comment: I'm not sure what the es5 syntax is that's equivalent to `extends`

Comment: @AymanMorsy [see here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56942974/). In ES5 "extending" is done as a more direct prototype manipulation. You'd create class A (or constructor function A) then create class B (or constructor function B). Afterwards set it up so B uses A's prototype but change the constructor of that prototype back to B, so you don't lose it. See also [What's the actual purpose of prototype.constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59715125) and the duplicate links from there.

Comment: @VLAZ does that have the same relationship as above with `instanceof` vs `instance.constructor`?

Comment: looks like it does actually.

Comment: @TKoL yes, `B extends A` will broadly do the same thing as the ES5 version. Overall, the class syntax is just syntactic sugar over the same prototype inheritance and mechanics which ES5 has, so both would work the same way. The major difference is that ES6 has the concept of constructable and non-constructable functions, so an ES6 class constructor cannot be called *without* `new` and ES6 class methods cannot be called *with* `new`. ES5 doesn't have away to enforce this, so you can call `MyConstructor()` or `new myInstance.myMethod()`. Other than that, the ES6 class syntax should work the same

Comment: Thanks guys for your times , I can add another example got inspired from this answer may help if anyone come here later : https://i.imgur.com/S6jQJGH.png